# How can i get a specific row in my database using id?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database with columns :id,question,answer1.
I want the user to enter the id and return the specific question everytime. I have a problem using the query!Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the fields of `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2`, and `id` is the row-ID:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN1, COLUMN2
                }, ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I have one question though. Does the above returns a cursor or the exact question?

Comment: II stopped after the query, but you can do whatever you want with this.